# How do I solve the issue where my django primary key (id) is null?

Tags: django, django-models

I am expecting that the primary key (id) to be inserted automatically E.g. 1
However, when I run my server, it is reflected as null instead.

I have tried deleting the migration and previous records in the database, but it still reflects a null value in new entries.

[null_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EqUW.png)

In my settings.py file, I have the following option on default
`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'`

I have the following Camera model
`class Camera(models.Model): status = models.BooleanField(default=True) location = models.CharField(max_length=2) liveURL = models.URLField(max_length=200)`

I created the Camera Object and save it using the django shell (python manage.py shell)
`test = Camera(status=False,location='b1',liveURL='http://test.com')`

I am using Django version 4.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the database you are using supports auto-incrementing fields. Some databases like SQLite do not support auto-incrementing fields by default.

You can specify the primary key in the model using the AutoField or BigAutoField.

**In Models :**

```py
class Camera(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    liveURL = models.URLField(max_length=200)
```

then run migrations

```py
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks Noriz for your insight. As I am new to using MongoDB, I did not realise that the database does not have a default support for auto-incrementing fields. While it is still possible to have auto-incrementing fields in MongoDB, it will require additional set-up to implement it.